# Best way to handle multiple API requests in Angular (no backend)

Tags: angular, api, github-pages, infinite-scroll

I am using GitHub pages to make a site to find TV series: the user can filter by many operators, including the number of episodes and seasons. I am using the TMDB API and the first call I make is: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv-discover: This does not allow me to filter by the number of eps and seasons. After this call I extract the IDs and, for each of them, call: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/tv/get-tv-details, which allows me to filter by eps and seasons. This method has also been confirmed by the API developers if I want to filter by ep and seasons.

Example: I want to find all shows with exactly 8 episodes, so I don't add any other filter except the status (in my case: Ended)

1. the first call (tv-discover) finds ~60k results, divided into ~3k pages (each of 20 elements - this can't be changed)

   [image: Result of the call]
2. I would then have to call the tv-discover method again for each page
3. For each element in the `results` array, I'd have to call tv-details, which would allow me to filter the results with exactly 8 episodes.

This is obviously unsustainable, as it would take minutes (if not hours) to complete. I thought about displaying the show info in a `MatCard`, possibly by using the infinite scroll technique. What is the best way to handle this situation? I am using Angular 15.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to be the one to post the bad news, but if the API you are forced to consume doesn't provide selection/filtering capability, you are out of luck.

My number one suggestion would be to create an issue for the API team, and ask for the feature to be added.

My number two request would be to push back on your product owner / stakeholders and ask them how important this feature is to them.  Is it worth 10 hours?  Is it worth 100?  1,000?

Finally, if your world will end if this feature isn't implemented, then I would suggest you write an ETL app to get all of this data into your own data store, one that provides selection/filtering capability, i.e. some type of database.  It means backend programming, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks, there are no stakeholders. It's a web app I'm doing for myself (since I can never find the TV Shows I want), so I'll ask the API developers. I could also run all the requests and save the answer to a local JSON, but this will need to be updated from time to time...